# It's regarding operation research cost model, can you please tell me how to solve this

Tags: operations-research

An author has option of either publishing his novel himself or through a publisher . Publisher is offering him $ 20000$ for signing contract.
 If novel is successful it would Sell 20000 copies , if not then 10000 copies. Publisher pays $1$ as royalty per copy. There is 70% chance that novel will be successful. 
If author published himself then initially he will incur cost of $ 90000$ for printing, but each copy sold will net him $2$. 
Based on above info , tell which option is more beneficial

Comment: Are you in a course that treats these things? Perhaps they have shown some examples ...

Answer (score 1):

We could view the problem from a probabilistic point of view. In this case, earning are a random variable because we don't know how many copies are sold. Let $X=$number of copies sold, with a probability density function
$$
P(X=x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
0.3 & \text{ if } x=10~000\\
0.7 & \text{ if } x=20~000\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
In the first case, we do take the publisher deal. Now the earnings are
$$
\text{Earnings}=20~000+1 \times X
$$
In the second option we print the book ourselves, and the earnings are
$$
\text{Earnings}=-90~000+2 \times X
$$
The next step is to consider the expected value from Earnings in each case. Can you take it from here?

PS: You could also consider what happens in the "best case scenario", where sales are indeed $20~000$ copies. What's the result then?